# How do I run code analysis for .NET application using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers from a command line interface

Tags: .net, .net-core, roslyn-code-analysis

**Setup:**

1. .NET Core 3.1 console app
2. Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers installed as a NuGet package

**Problem:**
I need to run code analysis from a command line interface to have it as a step in my CI (Continuous Integration) build process.

Ideally, I would like to have something similar to ESLint or TSLint running prior to building TypeScript applications and outputting all issues into console and not letting the build process going further in case of code analysis issues.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET analyzers run on a *build*.

By default, only some rules are enabled: see [Code quality analysis: Enabled rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview#enabled-rules). To enable all rules, you may set `<AnalysisMode>AllEnabledByDefault</AnalysisMode>` in your `.csproj` or a `Directory.Build.props` file in the project directory or above.

Most *Diagnostics* are reported with *Severity* `Warning`, so they will not break your build. But *MSBuild* also has the option to `TreatWarningsAsErrors`. I advice to only `TreatWarningsAsErrors` in *Release* builds (or non-*Debug* builds, depending on your preference), so that you can perform quick prototyping while coding and facilitate a satisfying TDD-cycle without worrying about each and every warning immediately during development. However, when you set your CI to build with *Release* *Configuration*, your pipeline will stop and fail if there is any *Warning* present (now treated as *Error*).

##### Example:

`.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <AnalysisMode>AllEnabledByDefault</AnalysisMode>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers" Version="5.0.3" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

`CLI`

```bsh
dotnet build --configuration Release
```

If there are any `Warning`s present, they are treated as `Error`s in *Release Configuration*, and `dotnet build` will terminate with a non-zero exit code, failing your CI pipeline.

I have tested this example utilizing the *.NET 5.0 SDK*.

Keep in mind, that with the *.NET 5.0 SDK* and higher, the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers` are included in the SDK and may be enabled via `<EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>`. If you prefer the NuGet package-based model for on-demand version updates though, you should not add the `EnableNETAnalyzers` property. And also keep in mind that the *.NET 6.0 SDK* offers a more fine-grained `AnalysisMode`: see [MSBuild: AnalysisMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#analysismode).

If you don't care about every *Diagnostic* from the analyzers and want to override the default severity of specific rules, you can add a [Global AnalyzerConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-files#global-analyzerconfig) (`.globalconfig`) file to your project directory or above to configure the analyzers with.

`.globalconfig` (AnalyzerConfig)

```
is_global = true

# CA1062: Validate arguments of public methods
dotnet_diagnostic.CA1062.severity = silent

# CA1707: Identifiers should not contain underscores
dotnet_diagnostic.CA1707.severity = silent

# CA2007: Consider calling ConfigureAwait on the awaited task
dotnet_diagnostic.CA2007.severity = silent
```

This example is taken from one of my unit test projects, where I don't want to validate my parameterized unit test methods, where I use underscores in my unit test method names, and where I don't care about `ConfigureAwait`.

With *AnalyzerConfig* files, you can control the severity for each rule and force it to be either `default`, `none`, `silent`, `suggestion`, `warning`, or `error`. See [Rule-specific options: Severity level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-options#severity-level).

Some rules offer additional configuration options. E.g. [CA2007](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2007) can be only applied to code that produce a certain `OutputType`, such as a `.dll`, via:

```
dotnet_code_quality.CA2007.output_kind = DynamicallyLinkedLibrary
```

I'm not exactly sure where to stop. Let me know if this answers your question or if I should give some more details. Here is the link of the official documentation on that topic (it's super comprehensive): [Code analysis: Overview of .NET source code analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview).

And remember, Roslyn is awesome!

Comment: If I can ask one more question - could you please advise a reporting tool or a viewer for a generated sarif file (for easier seeing and inspecting code analysis issues)

Comment: @DmitryMishin I'm afraid I haven't used SARIF so far .